# passing string values as labels for convolutional neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

working on a CNN model with a dataset of images, each one reading a 6 digit number, and their corresponding labels are the string values of the numbers in the image (e.g "658945"). therefore every label in the dataset is different from the other one and there is a label for every image in the dataset. i am aware that when passing the labels the way they are (as strings), i get this error: `'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. so what is the correct way to implement the labels. and should the neurons of the output layer be as many as the labels in the dataset?

UPDATE: here's the code:

```
x_train, y_train = create_training_data()

print(x_train)
print(y_train)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=25, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
```

x_train:

```
[[[[1.        ]
   [1.        ]
   [1.        ]
   ...
   [0.99215686]
   [0.99215686]
   [1.        ]]]]
```

y_train:

```
[['321043'], ['734231'], ['754946'], ['135039'], ['529285'], ['458224'], ['403070']...['533067'], ['185215'], ['495197'], ['100333']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `[["123456"],["654312"]]` instead of `["123456","654312"]` as your "list of labels".

EDIT:
`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` does not make sense as a loss function. You are trying to compare the output of your network (a floating point number) to your label (a string), that won't do. If you really need to train something yourself, you need to represent the strings as vectors.

So you have some options:
1) try something out of the box (recommended): https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr. You probably won't even have to retrain this. 
2) train your own and represent the strings as the a 60 dimensional vector. 6 digits and each digit can have 10 different chars [0-9], so 60. So your last dense layer will have 60 output neurons. This means that you have to encode your labels as such 60 output neurons, for example the string 123444 would be

```
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

You'll have to write some code that converts your string labels to such `one hot` encodings, are they are called. This is probably done most easily in `create_training_data`, not in `tensorflow`, but then the model will also output the 60-vector, not a string.

Comment: I did as you instructed, now the y_train is a list of one-element-lists. but now i get the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 120 arrays: [array([['321043']], dtype='<U6'), array([['734231']], dtype='<U6')`...and so on

Comment: what's `x_train.shape` give you?

Comment: (140, 130, 30, 1)

Comment: thank you for the time you put on this. I did as you said and now for every element in the list, there is a list of ones and zeros corresponding to the integer values of the strings. for example: this is `y_train[0]` : `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. but now error is: `Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 5384 arrays`. 5384 is the length of my y_train. I think this is getting out of hand haha